# Determine in there are Non Trivial Solutions for a a Second Order Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

The ODE is $$\frac{d^2w}{dx^2} + k^2w = 0$$ Where $k$ is some constant. We are given the initial conditions:  $$w(x=0) = 0$$ $$\frac{dw}{dx}(x=0) = 0$$ Part A asks to solve for any non-trivial solutions and  solve $k$ for them. When attempting the general solution I found: $$w(x)= c_1 \sin(kx) + c_2 \cos(kx)$$ Solving for the first condition: $$0= c_1 \sin(0) + c_2 \cos(0) \to c_2=0$$ But solving for the second condition gave me: $$\frac{dw}{dx}=c_1k\cos(kx)-c_2k\sin(kx)$$$$0=c_1k\cos(0)-c_2k\sin(0)\to c_1k=0$$ The only way to make this true would be setting either $c_1$ or $k$ equal to zero, and both of those possibilities result in trivial solutions. Parts B and C rely on the fact that there are non-trivial solutions, and I'm unsure of any way to double check if I'm correct. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You have an initial value linear ODE problem and so the solution if it exists is unique. Since 0 is a solution, it is in fact the only solution. Perhaps you wrote it wrong?

**EDIT** Linearity is not necessary, but your ODE satisfies the conditions for uniqueness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem